# Storing checkbox value into database. HTML, PHP, CSS

Tags: php, html, css

How to store these two checkbox values into database? I have tried so far, but it only stores 0 even if checkbox is checked... Any advices?

```
    <form action="" method="post" class="contact100-form validate-form" id="check" autocomplete="off">
        
        <p><input type="checkbox" id="C1" name="C1" value="1"> Text1</p>
        
        <p><input type="checkbox" id="C2" name="C2" value="1"> Text2</p>

            <div class="container-contact100-form-btn" style="padding-top: 30px; justify-content: center; display: flex;">
            <button  class="contact100-form-btn" type="submit" id="register" name="create" input type="submit">
                <span><strong style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">
                    Submit
                    </strong></span>
            </button>
            </div>
    </form>

<?php
require_once('config.php');
?>
<?php
        if(isset($_POST)){
        $C1 = ((isset($_POST['C1']))&&($_POST['C1'] == '1'))? 1 : 0;
        $C2 = ((isset($_POST['C2']))&&($_POST['C2'] == '1'))? 1 : 0;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO test2 (C1, C2) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sql);

$result = $stmtinsert->execute([$C1, $C2]);
?>
```

Comment: This code would throw exceptions. You have not closed your try catch block and you have an extra closing round bracket here: 
  $C1 = ((isset($_POST['C1']))&&($_POST['C1'] == '1'))? 1 : 0;
and 
  $C2 = ((isset($_POST['C2']))&&($_POST['C2'] == '1'))? 1 : 0;

Comment: Yes, I just didn't place full code here so, try catch is not here. What about extra closing round bracket - code gives error. It says that semicolon is not necessary then.

Comment: Oh sorry I read that wrong. You don't need the brackets around the isset though. That just makes it hard to read. What do you get if you just echo $_POST['C1']

Comment: You aren't closing the input tags.